# NodeJS - Generate OAuth 1.0a signature

Tags: node.js, firebase, oauth

**Is there a standardized way to generate an `oauth_signature` for OAuth 1.0a in NodeJS?**

---

**Attempt 1 (+?)**

In [Intuit's Documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app#/OAuth_Community_Resources) (which is what I need the signature for), it is stated that `oauth_signature` is needed for Getting the OAuth request token:

> *oauth_signature*   A unique string your app generates for each request. Do not attempt to generate this value manually, but rather use one of several [OAuth community resources](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app#OAuth_Community_Resources) as appropriate to your language.

Those [OAuth community resources](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app#OAuth_Community_Resources) list the following for NodeJS:

- [NodeJS OAuth 2.0 Provider](https://github.com/t1msh/node-oauth20-provider)
- [Mozilla Firefox Accounts.](https://github.com/mozilla/?query=fxa) A full stack
  Identity Provider system developed to support Firefox Marketplace and
  other services
- [OAuth2orize: toolkit to implement OAuth2 Authorization
  Servers](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize)

I have looked through **each** resource, but it seems that each is for OAuth2.0 (not OAuth 1.0a) and not have a clear way to generate the `oauth-signature` (though hopefully I'm missing something here).

---

**Attempt 2**

I found an [npm project for generating an `oauth_signature`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth-signature) and attempted implementing and testing it as instructed by the documentation:

```
var httpMethod = 'GET',
    url = 'http://photos.example.net/photos',
    parameters = {
        oauth_consumer_key : 'dpf43f3p2l4k3l03',
        oauth_token : 'nnch734d00sl2jdk',
        oauth_nonce : 'kllo9940pd9333jh',
        oauth_timestamp : '1191242096',
        oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_version : '1.0',
        file : 'vacation.jpg',
        size : 'original'
    },
    consumerSecret = 'kd94hf93k423kf44',
    tokenSecret = 'pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00',
    // generates a RFC 3986 encoded, BASE64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 hash 
    encodedSignature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret),
    // generates a BASE64 encode HMAC-SHA1 hash 
    signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret,
        { encodeSignature: false});
```

However, this did not work and I also noticed that the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth-signature)'s **Dependency Status is [Insecure](https://david-dm.org/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js)**.  According to further digging, there are **security vulnerabilities** in its dependencies, which makes me feel as though I shouldn't be using this at all.

---

Any direction no how to a generate an oauth_signature for OAuth 1.0a would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Found solution ?